# Decreasing Image Size with Minimal Quality Loss?

Tags: preview, image-editing, graphics

I have a few scanned in images of some some pages that I need to digitise. They're each roughly around 5.1MB with 600 DPI, but I can't really afford to have scans so large because I only have around 16GB to last for another 7 months.

I want to decrease the image size but I need to have minimal quality loss of the image. Can this be done?

Comment: Any image editing program will allow you to do that, but the question would be better posted in http://photo.stackexchange.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ (my two cents)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Preview, and select `Adjust Size` from the `Tools` menu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the dimensions of the image (ex. 400px x 600px) or the size of the file?

Some image formats use smaller file sizes just because it's in the nature of the format. For example, PSDs tend to be larger then PNGs, etc. I personally use the PNG format for my images, since the images still look nice without being too bulky in size.

A good tool for resizing images or converting them to different types is Image Tool (http://mac-free.com/download/Image-Tool.html) and it's free as well. Hope this helps.